# Determine what is inserting blank rows into mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, logging

So I've come into a role at a new company and one of the big issues we're facing is our reporting/accounting site breaking due to *something* that I can't quite figure out. The way it works is we use JIRA for staff worklogs, which get imported into a hosted MYSQL database, which the reporting site reads from. We've narrowed the cause of the site breaking to empty rows being inserted into various tables in the DB, removing the rows instantly fixes the problem (but causes a loss for any progress for accounting that's been done so far). There are a number of scripts being run as cronjobs on the web server running the MYSQL database which does the bulk of the importing but I haven't a clue of where to start looking to find the problem. Is there a way I can check logs within MYSQL to see what or when one of the blank rows was inserted?

Answer (score 2):

You need to improve the design of your database. You should update your schema to add restrictions to the fields that cause troubles when data is set empty. Then do a full integration testing on your QA environment of each one of your integrations, those injecting null values will start to fail. Finally you have to fix every integration broken by preventing inserting null values.